# How to get all NFTs in a Collection? (Solana, Metaplex)

Tags: solana, nft, solana-web3js, metaplex, anchor-solana

- On the client side (JavaScript)
- Assume we have the address of the Collection mint

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with Code you can find sample implementations on GitHub here https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/get-collection

Basically you have to get all transactions of the collection mint, parse them and save the mints.